# Adding labels to scatter plot points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble adding labels to points on a scatter plot using ggplot. Instead of adding the country name, it is adding the row number. What changes to geom_text do I need to make to fix this?

```
ggplot(data = World, aes(x = pop_age, y = peace_index_score, label = country)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "Youth Buldge and Instability", x = "Median Age in Country",y = "Overall Peacefulness of Country") + theme_economist() + ylim(0,4) + xlim(15,45) + geom_smooth(method = lm, color = "red") + geom_text(aes(label=country))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the variable country contains the names? Can you share your data with dput(World) ?

Comment: ```head(World$country)```

value
<chr>
label
<chr>
1 Afghanistan   
2 Albania   
3 Algeria   
4 Angola   
5 Argentina   
6 Armenia   
7 Australia   
8 Austria   
9 Azerbaijan   
10 Bahrain

Comment: you also may want to try ggrepel https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_point(data = World, aes(x = pop_age, y = peace_index_score)) + 
 labs(title = "Youth Buldge and Instability", x = "Median Age in Country",y = "Overall Peacefulness of Country") + 
 theme_economist() + 
 ylim(0,4) + 
 xlim(15,45) + 
 geom_smooth(data = World, aes(x = pop_age, y = peace_index_score), method = lm, color = "red") + 
 geom_text(data = World, aes(x = pop_age, y = peace_index_score, label = country))
```

Comment: No, I am still having the same issue. When I call ```head(World$country)``` it returns ```
value
<chr>
label
<chr>
1 Afghanistan   
2 Albania   
3 Algeria   
4 Angola   
5 Argentina   
6 Armenia   
7 Australia   
8 Austria   
9 Azerbaijan   
10 Bahrain ```
It looks like the country name is just a label. Is there an easier way to fix this other than performing a join with the ccode variable and an ISO 3166-1 dataset?